# VS code icons disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

File icons in my VS Code disappeared when I installed [Material icon theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme) and disabled it but now when I'm enabling this extension or reinstalling it, icons are not appearing. Even the default VS code file icons which were there before installing the extension have somehow disappeared as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked the  `"workbench.iconTheme"` setting?

Comment: It's set to "vscode-icons"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set `“workbench.iconTheme“: “material-icon-theme“`.
Then reloading the window should fix it.

Answer (score 25):

Based on my own experience, the theme was being deselected due to some reason (e.g installed a new theme, application update and etc). You can fix it by re-selecting the icon theme:

Open VS Code, go to File > Preferences > File icon theme > [Theme name] and choose your icon theme.

Answer (score 12):

In VS Code, Go to extensions <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>X</kbd> .

Under installed extensions, select the `vscode-icons extension`. And Click on Set File Icon Theme, as shown in figure below, then press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the extension again. 
I am on Mac, so I had to go to Preferences -> Extensions, and searched for Material Icon Theme, installed it and relaunched the IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking if folders theme is set to 'classic' worked here. If so, either deselect it (1) or remove the line in User Settings (2):

[image: vscode-material-icons-folders.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had installed 'Material Icon Theme' extension but it it was not working. So i had to go to extension section of VS code, click on 'Material Icon Theme' extension (already installed). And click on 'Set File Icon Theme' button, a dropdown with 'Material Icon Theme' will be displayed. Select it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem except with more of the main icons in code missing too, but the above didn't help although it's best to check them first.

I resolved my problem by fixing the registry item:
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.svg`

setting "Content Type" Data to "image/svg+xml"
(mine was incorrectly set to "text/xml" unsure why)

Answer (score 0):

In installed **Material Icon** on vs Code Extension. sometimes not working that's why showing this.

see the image and click the set file icon theme and finally, the problem is solved.
I'm also facing this problem.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ1b7.png)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac:

Code(top bar) > Settings... > Theme > File icon theme > [Theme name] and choose your icon theme (i suggest "*material icon theme*").

Answer (score -1):

ctrl + shift + p then search for the activity bar then enter