# How to restore VS Code's default file icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-icons

Any idea on how to restore the default VS Code seti file icons? This is what I see, I only have my installed Material UI icons.

[image: file icon setting]

I deleted them a while back and now I want them back. I have not tried deleting user data or a fresh reinstall yet. Is there a way to add them back manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS code icons disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876850/vs-code-icons-disappeared)

Comment: @GinoMempin no my icons didnt disappear i deleted them a while back but dont know how to get them back

Comment: I know that your icons didn't disappear, but your question is basically the same: how to get the seti file icons theme back. Have you checked all the answers there, like this answer about *reinstalling* the extension for the icons? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56354622/2745495

Comment: @GinoMempin yea but the seti file icons were not an extension they were built-in vscode

Comment: how did you delete them?

Comment: i think inside settings when you go to pick the icon theme there's an option to delete