# Why did my VSCode file icons suddenly disappear?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code file icons suddenly disappeared

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFagd.png)

I tried re-opening the folder, opening another folder, restarting my PC and restarting VS Code. Nothing worked.

Please help me, I want to code soon. I double checked everything

Comment: can this solve your problem [VS code icons disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876850/vs-code-icons-disappeared)?

Answer (score 0):

Click the `gear button > theme > file icon theme` then choose the icon theme from it.

You can also install a file icon theme from Extensions marketplace.